# Detect when a user is fully logged on computer

Tags: c#, windows

Problem:
I have to start internet explorer to a spesfic web site eatch time a user loggs on either localy on in citrix ( So in effect it gets started 2 times for citrix users) this is mandated by the highest bosses.

I know i can use group policy to do this, but i was wondering if i could do the following to improve user experience.

1) Start a program in startup ( Minimal app that i make ).
2) Have this program wait untill the user is fully connected, and then start IE.

Now my problem is whats a good method of detecting when a user is fully logged in ( My definition of this is, that the computer/session is in a state where it responds to user input and he can start the applications he/she wants to use).

If anyone has a clever way to detect this, please tell me how. Trying to search for this either on SO or internet it gets me nothing usefull ( IE SO is now trying to tell me how to detect who is logged in).

Just tested using a sleep style solution, and its not good as it does not take into account different login times. So its a bad solution ( Reason why there is no accepted reply)

Comment: I think you should keep it simple and add a `start http://[website]` to the autostart of the users. Then focus on improving the startup time for everything rather than trying to work around it for one specific problem.

Comment: @Anders you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Commen "trick" to avoid downvoting.

Comment: @Toby: Done. 
@EKS: I didn't belive that it had enough substance to be an answer, and my answer is with the best intentions. I added a few lines of my reasoning behind the suggestion.

Comment: Your reply is better then you comment, to the point im not gonna down vote it. I agree with your suggestion, but sometimes you cannot fix all the problems but focus on making sure you dont create new once.

Answer (score 1):

> My definition of this is, that the computer/session is in a state where it responds to user input and he can start the applications he/she wants to use

I think you'll find this isn't sufficiently specific.

Eg. I have startup applications some of which take several tens of seconds to be in a usable state, well before that point I can launch other applications that are (essentially) immediately available.

Task Scheduler (in Win7 at least, and probably Vista) allows tasks to be triggered at logon but with a delay, to say a minute after logon to start.

Comment: I have no problem with the application not starting for a several seconds after the user can start his program. So in short you would use a timer for this?

Comment: @EKS: The delayed start is part of Task Scheduler.

Comment: Just checked, the citrix servers are 2003 based so task scheduler did not have the option. But using this timer based is off course a option

Answer (score 1):

My 2¢:

I think you should [keep it simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and add a `start http://[website]` to the autostart of the users. Then focus on improving the startup time for everything rather than trying to work around it for one specific problem.

Writing an application to detect the responsiveness of a system will no doubt be hard, and it is very likely that you will run into problems originating from differences between the clients that are hard to anticipate and account for. You could easily spend tens of hours developing and debugging this. On the other hand, using the straight-forward and OS-supported solution will buy you time to look into the real problem of startup time.

The [`start` command](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntstart.php) has priority settings, that might be worth examining.

Answer (score 0):

Using something like .Net would be over-engineering IMO.

I'd write a really simple VBScript file which is executed upon logon, using your preferred method of kicking it off.

The script would essentially [sleep](http://ss64.com/vb/sleep.html) for a specified amount of time to allow for logon to settle down/complete, then [run](http://ss64.com/vb/run.html) "iexplore.exe http://www.yourdomain.com" afterwards.

No popup cmd windows to annoy anyone or for people to close down.

Quite, unobtrusive, simple, effective.